# Why does my App gets logged out automatically?

Tags: android

I have checked the loggedin status in the splash screen.I have saved the logged in status in the SharedPreferences.It works certain time period. I am getting **false** when I print the login status from the SharedHelper and app gets logged out without pressing the logout button. I have implemented as follows:

```
  handleCheckStatus.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.w("Handler", "Called");
            if (helper.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                if (SharedHelper.getKey(context, "loggedIn").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    showDialog();
                    GetToken();
                    SharedHelper.putKey(context,"loggedIn","true");
                    GoToMainActivity();
                } else {
                    GoToBeginActivity();
                    handleCheckStatus.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }
                if (alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            } else {
                showDialog();
                handleCheckStatus.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

public void GetToken() {
    try {
        if (!SharedHelper.getKey(context, "device_token").equals("") && SharedHelper.getKey(context, "device_token") != null) {
            device_token = SharedHelper.getKey(context, "device_token");
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + device_token);
        } else {
            device_token = "" + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            SharedHelper.putKey(context, "device_token", "" + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh: " + device_token);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        device_token = "COULD NOT GET FCM TOKEN";
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
    }

    try {
        device_UDID = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Log.i(TAG, "Device UDID:" + device_UDID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        device_UDID = "COULD NOT GET UDID";
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete device UDID");
    }
}
```

My SharedHelper class. I have implemented SharedHelper class as follows:

```
public class SharedHelper {

public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public static void putKey(Context context, String Key, String Value) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Key, Value);
    editor.commit();

}

public static String getKey(Context contextGetKey, String Key) {
    sharedPreferences = contextGetKey.getSharedPreferences("Cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Value = sharedPreferences.getString(Key, "");
    return Value;

}

public static void clearSharedPreferences(Context context)
{
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
}
}
```

Comment: can you post your SharedHelper file?

Comment: @Nbn your question title looks good, but the content is discouraging, I assumed you already know the line of code causing bug in your project, and so you want to know why. Also, the way you used try and catch is making your code almost unreadable.
Try removing the try and catch and start debugging what causes the crash, that might actually be where the bug is from.

Comment: where do you set loggedIn to true?

Comment: @Zaartha loggedIn is set true when user logs in, This is code is of the Splash Screen.